# Can I cancel a controller request half way in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Am very new to ASP MVC

I have a list of menu options that the user can choose. Each menu selection triggers one controller as per MVC architecture .

But unfortunately some of these controllers take some time for execution to make a visible change. Because the large data needs to be binded to a grid.So all that time browser hangs(shows loading).

The worst case occurs if user selects an option which could be easily loaded, after a time consuming menu option.

Can someone help on how to dismiss one controller action request if another comes in?
Right now its the summation of all user selected actions

Eg: If user selects  Menu1 and after that Menu2 . And my Menu1 controller action  is taking some time to execute. By that time User clicks Menu2 which is easily loaded if clicked for first time. But since Menu2 is clicked user has to wait a long.

Comment: You should use ajax to do the request, upon too long, abort the ajax request. The server side will still complete the request though. And also using time consuming process in an Action will lock the user from opening another Action even you use Ajax, this is because of same session being locked into one request at a time. My suggestion would be disabling ASP.NET Session and implement your own session

Comment: Can I have more than one request in a ASP.Net session

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old but I will attempt to answer anyway since I ran into this problem recently. If you are using MVC 5, the other requests can be cancelled for you. The trick is to use async controller actions and to add a CancellationToken parameter.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyReallySlowReport(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    List<ReportItem> items;
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        items = await context.ReportItems.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    return View(items);
}
```

When the user navigates to another page, the request is cancelled. MVC will signal to the cancellation token that the request has been cancelled. As long as you also pass the cancellation token to the async data access method like I did above, the query will be cancelled and the server will stop working on the request immediately.

I have put together a full explanation here: http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx

Comment: Is there any way of doing this in asp. Net mvc4 with .net4?

Comment: how about when the user sends a more specific request, how can you trigger the cancellation from the client instead of just a navigation?

Comment: @ChrisHayes In that case you would cancel the requests by calling the abort method on each individual request. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

Comment: @DavidPaquette there is a tag on the question "asp.net-mvc3". So I guess your response does not apply.

Comment: Can i do this in Asp.NET web form ? , can you answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324184/asp-net-while-first-request-processing-allow-second-request-on-click) question ? I am trying cancel request  without `async`. Is concurrent request possible using `async` ?