# asp.net while first request processing allow second request on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

In Asp.net Web Form app, I have Generate Report button and a Cancel button to cancel report generation process, if it takes a long time.

When I Click Generate Report it does the heavy task, after 3 seconds I try to cancel this heavy task by clicking the Cancel button.

But the server side code for Cancel button click is called after some time delay.

I even tried `window.stop()` in `JavaScript` to stop page loading and hit server code fast, but still, there is a delay.

**Code:**

```
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

// Doing Heavy Task to Generate Report

}


protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
    {

       HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

    }
}     

  <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel Request" 

  OnClientClick="return StopPageLoading();" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />


 function StopPageLoading() {

     try
     {
       window.stop();
     } catch (exception) 
     {
       document.execCommand('Stop'); // for IE and other browsers
     }

  }
```

How can I allow to start another request on click fast, while current request is in processing?

How to allow `UI` to be responsive?

**Update:**

To reproduce the situation:

1. I click Export To Excel , it takes 7 minutes to process.
2. While still processing I click Cancel button , it takes another 5 minutes to cancel.

I read that [Concurrent request](http://hogaf.github.io/archive/2014/11/13/why-asp.net-requests-are-processed-sequentially) is not possible in Asp.NET because of session state makes exclusive locks.

So How to cancel fast ?

Will making my methods `async` help to overcome session state exclusive locks issue ?

Comment: can you tell us what .Net-Framework Version do you work with?

Comment: and from how much delay do you speek when you click the cancel button?

Comment: You will have to use ajax calls to a webservice/api to make the UI responsive. You cannot do that with a normal PostBack.

Comment: @VDWWD , Ok lets say `ExportExcel` click is normal `PostBack` call ,  and Cancel button click is ajax call. Will cancel button click event will hit fast while`ExportExcel` click is in processing ?

Comment: @Darem , I am using `.NET 4.5` and delay is 5 minutes, After clicking Export to excel I wait for 5 minutes and while it is still processing , I click the cancel button, now it should stop the processing fast. But it takes time to cancel.

Comment: @stom but when you click the "Cancel-Button" how long does it take until ONLY the request hit the server. So how long does it takes until your "Cancel-Method" is called.

Comment: `btnExportExcel_Click`executes on one server thread and `btnCancel_Click` executes on another server thread. So the only way is to set some shared (across threads)  "stop" state from `btnCancel_Click` and periodically checks for that state in `btnExportExcel_Click` and stop the heavy work when that state has been set to stop.

Comment: @Darem please check my update.

Comment: @SimonMourier , are you talking about `async` in .NET ? Will making my methods `async` help to overcome session state exclusive locks issue ?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about async stuff. async is no magic. Once a piece of code is started, it needs to checks sometimes if it's required to stop (otherwise another thread could terminate it but that's baaaaaad design)

Comment: @stom the question is do you need the session to generate the report?

Comment: @Darem , no , I just want cancel the current server request which is not possible. Because  Concurrent request is not possible in Asp.NET because of session state makes exclusive locks.

Comment: @stom I post an anwser. As in the link you posted sayed you have to set EnableSessionsState to false.

Comment: @stom did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300617/cancel-current-synchronous-request-processing/51318983#51318983) from you, you can do it this way

```
public partial class Contact : Page
{

    private static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected async void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationToken cToken = tokenSource.Token;
        cToken.Register(() => cancelNotification());

        try
        {

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                cToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                GenerateReport(sender, cToken);

            }, cToken);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {

        }
    }

    private void GenerateReport(object sender, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // Just to Simulate Export to excel

        Thread.Sleep(70000);
    }


    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tokenSource.Cancel();

    }


    private static void cancelNotification()
    {
        // Do your stuff when the user is canceld the report generation

    }
}
```

And in your `Page.aspx`

Need something like this

```
<%@ Page Async="true" EnableSessionState="false" %>
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Though, you can do it or not (I am not sure), it is generally not a good idea to create a long running task within ASP.NET, especially if they are background tasks.
So there are some helper libraries that are for this purpose.

1. HangFire http://docs.hangfire.io
   Hangfire allows you to kick off method calls outside of the request processing pipeline in a very easy, but reliable way. These method invocations are performed in a background thread and called background jobs.
   this support using cancellation tokens to cancel a background job
2. Quarz.NET
   I have never tryed Quarz.NET
3. Or you have to do it yourself. I know some projecs that take some dedicate servers just for run background and time consuming tasks. So the website is just a frontend layer that set some flags that control the task is cancel or not

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in IIS (or any other Web Server) architecture. The server returns a response to a client (browser) and **forget it**. Your first request (`btnExcelExport_Click`) must be finished before it returns response to the browser. The click on `btnCancel` starts a new request which knows nothing about the first one.
The workaround is to send a long job to another `thread`. It is possible to communicate to that thread using state `object` sent to the new thread. Something like this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

    protected void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var jobState = new StateInfo()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Counter = 0,
            Content = "Start the job",
            Cancelled = false,
            Completed = false
        };
        Session["job"] = jobState; //Save state between requests
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            new System.Threading.WaitCallback(LongJob),
            jobState
            );//returns immediately
        lblState.Text += "<br />" + jobState.Counter.ToString() 
            + " Completed: " + jobState.Completed.ToString()
            + " Cancelled: " + jobState.Cancelled.ToString()
            + "<br />" + jobState.Content;
        btnCancel.Visible = true;
        btnCheck.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var jobState = Session["job"] as StateInfo;
        if (!jobState.Completed)
            jobState.Cancelled = true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);//wait for the next loop to complete
        lblState.Text += "<br />" + jobState.Counter.ToString()
            + " Completed: " + jobState.Completed.ToString()
            + " Cancelled: " + jobState.Cancelled.ToString()
            + (jobState.Completed || jobState.Cancelled ? "<br />" + jobState.Content : "");
    }

    protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var jobState = Session["job"] as StateInfo;
        lblState.Text += "<br />" + jobState.Counter.ToString()
            + " Completed: " + jobState.Completed.ToString()
            + " Cancelled: " + jobState.Cancelled.ToString()
            + (jobState.Completed || jobState.Cancelled ? "<br />" + jobState.Content : "");
    }

    private void LongJob(object state)
    {
        var jobState = state as StateInfo;
        do
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            jobState.Counter++;
            if (jobState.Counter >= 100)
            {
                jobState.Completed = true;
                jobState.Content = "The job is completed";
            }
            else if (jobState.Cancelled)
                jobState.Content = "The job is cancelled";
        }
        while (!jobState.Cancelled && !jobState.Completed);
    }
    [Serializable]
    class StateInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool Cancelled { get; set; }
        public bool Completed { get; set; }
    }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Long Job</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRun" OnClick="btnRun_Click" Text="Run" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCheck" OnClick="btnCheck_Click" Text="Check State" Visible="false" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" Text="Cancel" Visible="false" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the async/await operation in the code instead of synchronous

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

when the report generation call is asynchronous then redirect to UI once the report generation process is kicked off. Now the cancel button can be clicked when needed.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for writing, We are not using `async/await` in project , so I don't want implement it without having deep knowledge about it, because if not implemented correctly it can break existing functionality.  So Do you have solution for synchronous request ?

Comment: Please check if your report service (at IIS level) or in SQL connection can have a time out set and return an exception and the exception can be returned to UI. Other option is to use threading and abort after a specific time.

Comment: This statement `then redirect to UI once the report generation process is kicked off`, I dint understand.